Hibernate - @OneToMany mappedBy to inherit abstract class
I have a structure which looks like :
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Container {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Component extends Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_container")
    private Container parentContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Component> content = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Section extends Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_section")
    private Section parentContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Container> children = new HashSet<>();

}

So, we have two classes, Component and Section, which are both Containers. A section could contain subsections and components (ie. containers) and a component could contain only subcomponent.
When I launch this code, I have this following exception :
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection 'xxx.entities.Section.children' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'parentContainer' which does not exist in the target entity 'xxx.entities.Container'

All my inheritance classes of Container implements the parentContainer attribute but i would not like put this attribute in the Container class. Is this possible ?

I couldn't understand why you are using Container as super class and property at the same time.
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

You are using this annotation so subclass already related with super class 1..n One To Many relation. So let's change the Component class.
EDIT: Okay, I am assuming your Container is Parent of another Container so we can solve it like.
@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Component extends Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_container")
    private Container parentContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Component> content = new HashSet<>();

}

You are used Polymorphism on Component class and it is worked. As you say

a Component can have subcomponents but cannot have subsections.

Component is subclass of Container so it has properties of Container and parentContainer is property of Component so it can see the property and able to mapping.
@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Section extends Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_section")
    private Section parentContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Container> children = new HashSet<>();

}

In the Section class, you are trying to map Section with Container but there is a problem in there. Container doesn't have parentContainer property, Section has. So your exception says

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection 'xxx.entities.Section.children' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'parentContainer' which does not exist in the target entity 'xxx.entities.Container'

because of it. It says Container doesn't have parentContainer. I hope I could be clear so how can we solve it. As the simple way you can add Section parent on Container but it is not effective for polymorphic solution. But we can use hibernates beauty :
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Container {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_container")
    private Container parentContainer;
}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Component extends Container {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Component> content = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Section extends Container {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_section")
    private Section parentContainer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
    private Set<Container> children = new HashSet<>();

}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_section")
private Section parentContainer;

parentContainer will be Container except Section and we override it on Section class. I think overriding can be good solution.
public class Section extends Container { //You inherit it there

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) // InheritanceType using JOIN so it will add only one foreign key on your subtable (the foreign key is primary key of super table)
public abstract class Container {


JOINED: With this strategy, each class in the hierarchy is mapped to its own table, but only the properties specific to that class are included in the table. The tables are linked using foreign keys, and a discriminator column is used in the base table to identify the subclass. This strategy provides a good balance between query performance and data integrity, but it requires additional joins when querying across the hierarchy.

https://medium.com/@iampraveenkumar/mastering-jpa-inheritance-strategies-hibernate-6-x-jpa-3-x-spring-boot-3-x-06eecac1147a
And if it is not enough Baeldung is good source.
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance
Good luck :)

Thank you for your answer. A Container is in a property in inherited classes because a Section can have subsections and subcomponents (so subcontainers). But, a Component can have subcomponents but cannot have subsections. So, Component and Section have both a parent Container (Component's parent is Section or Component, Section's parent is only Section)

You are welcome. OK but I didn't say that. You shouldn't use
@ManyToOne     @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_container")     private Container parentContainer; 
because you are used JOINED on Container. And after that, cause of error is

`@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_parent_container")
private Container parentContainer;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentContainer")
private Set<Component> content = new HashSet<>();

`
parentContainer's type is not Component, it is Container so you must be more careful. I cannot be mapped for Container.
